# Random height with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a problem. I want a image to appear on random heights.
This is the coding:

```
$("#duck").css({
     #duck{ top: Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1);%; }
});
```

Can someone tell me what I need to change?

Comment: That's not how `.css()` works. Re-read [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/css/).

Comment: I'm very new to this and I'm doing this project to get more experience with it. How should I use it?

Comment: `$("#duck").height( Math.floor( (Math.random()*100)+1))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to do this:

```
$("#duck").css("top", Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1));
```

[jQuery CSS Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Comment: This isn't the image height though, this is the image offset.

Comment: "to appear on random heights", I believe that @Thomas wants the image to appear at a random offset (height from top)

Comment: Thank you so much! But just another question: Can this work with precentages to or yes pixels? So yes, what do I change?

Comment: Yes it can! just add the `+ "%"` to the code, like this: `$("#duck").css("top", Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1) + "%");`

Answer (score 0):

You can Try:

```
function getRandom(min, max) {
return min + Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1));
}

setInterval(function(){
var randomtop=(getRandom(0,($(window).height()-$("#duck").height())+"px");
$("#duck").css("top",randomtop);
},5000)
```